# Load a video before the displaying web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website where they want to add a video, but first we want the video to load and then the website is displayed.

I already have the video uploaded.

I just want the video to be shown first and then the web content

```
<center><video id="myVideo" src="http://as2.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/325cc0361862066dc06e8fb1fc7ec8a77684093-240p__39060.mp4" autoplay style="border-radius:5px;width:100%;"></video></center>
```

I have the idea that JS can be used, to run when the document loads, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Do you want the video to have fully loaded and buffered or just enough to start playing?

Comment: @Ameer Hi, just enough to start playing

Comment: What have you tried already? What do you want displayed before the video is loaded? [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) you can see what events you can listen for.